# How to resolve this Assertion Nontype error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, appium, python-appium

```
def teatDown(cls)

self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'assertEqual'
```

Comment: use your desired ouput instead of `[]` in `self.assertEqual()`

Answer (score 0):

Seems your teatDown is a ClassMethod( https://medium.com/@gmotzespina/method-types-in-python-2c95d46281cd)

you should use `cls.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)`

Hope it helps.